# Checking if a selected element contains an attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, if-statement, jquery-selectors

I have two types of lists appended to my select element.

a list of users: `<option value="domain\davidr" userid="108">David</option>`

a list of groups: `<option value="Test Group" groupid="10">Test Group</option>`

This is my select html:

```
    <select id="groupOwner">
      <option value="default" disabled>Select a Group Owner</option>
      <optgroup label="---Users---"></optgroup>
    </select>
```

I need to set a variable as either "user" or "group" based on the selected list item type.

I tried doing this: `var ownerType = $("#groupOwner[groupid]") ? "group" : "user";` but it keeps returning "group"

Comment: I was talking about the missing `="..."` part, but I carefully used _'looks'_ because I am not very sure if it is wrong or correct

Comment: It works fine like this. I don't think you need to write out the entire disabled="disabled"

Comment: my mistake, apparently that is correctly written https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/optgroup#Example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, `groupid` and `userid` are not valid attributes for the `option` element and will render your page invalid. Use `data-*` attributes instead:

```
<!-- Example user item -->
<option value="domain\davidr" data-userid="108">David</option>

<!-- Example group item -->
<option value="Test Group" data-groupid="10">Test Group</option>
```

Secondly, `#groupOwner` is the select, whereas you need to check the data attribute of the selected `option`. Try this:

```
var ownerType = $("#groupOwner option:selected").data('groupid') ? "group" : "user";
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/RN3kc/)

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was trying to accomplish. On a side note, what are the consequences if the page renders invalid, for me it seems to be working fine. Other people have also suggested not using custom attributes, so I thought I'd ask why.  Thanks again.

Comment: No problem, glad to help. If a page is invalid it renders in Quirks mode which can lead to jQuery selectors not working as you'd expect and various layout issue relating to elements being opened/closed where you are not expecting.

Comment: Oh okay I see. So to make sure my page renders as expected I should probably fix that. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Your selector will always be evaluated to true: if there's no match for your selector, jQuery returns an empty array, which will be evaluated to `true` in your ternary test.

You should **test the length of the array returned by jQuery** to determine whether your element is on the DOM or not.

Example :

```
// Will print No, foo isn't an HTML element present on the DOM
$('foo').length ? console.log('Yes') : console.log('No');

// Will print Yes, $('foo') = []
$('foo') ? console.log('Yes') : console.log('No');
```

Answer (score 0):

$("selector").get(0).hasAttributes("attributes");